# iOS - Urban Airship - handle multiple background remote notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

This is when the app is in **background**

It works fine when I send one push notification at a time, app processes the notification and `completionHandler` for `UAPushNotificationDelegate` is called.

The problem happens when I send two push notifications together, (second is sent immediately before the first is processed)

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called from the SDK and `completionHandler` is called before the second notification is handled in the SDK so where I implemented the `UAPushNotificationDelegate` method
`receivedBackgroundNotification:(UANotificationContent *)notificationContent completionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`, 
app crashes complaining `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x103b496f0)` which means it is trying to access the `completionHandler` which is already been released by the SDK.

How do I handle this?

Comment: Could you post your delegate/completion handler code? Probably better to file an issue on https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library instead of posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return `completionHandler` for `receivedBackgroundNotification:(UANotificationContent *)notificationContent completionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` immediately when a push notification is received and perform tasks after that since iOS wakes up app for 30 seconds.

this worked for me, Haven't had this crash since the change.